# Read, then Write CSV with "Non-ISO extended-ASCII" text Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x

My csv has strings like:

```
TîezÑnmidnan
```

I'm trying to use the following below to set up a reader/writer

```
import csv

# File that will be written to
csv_output_file = open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
# File that will be read in
csv_file = open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
# Define reader
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
# Define writer
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_output_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Then iterating over the information read in

```
# Iterate over the rows in the csv
for idx, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
    csv_writer.writerow(row[0:30])
```

Problem is in my output file I can't get it to show up with that same string. According to my mac, the csv file type has the encoding "Non-ISO extended-ASCII"

I tried various encodings and some would just remove the special characters while others just wouldn't work.

It's weird because I can hard code that string above into a variable and use it without problems, so I assume it's something to do with how I'm reading in the file. If I breakpoint before it writes it shows up as the following in the debugger.

```
T�ez�nmidnan
```

I can't convert the file before running it, so the python code has to handle any conversions itself.

The expected output I want would be for it to remain in the output file looking like

```
TîezÑnmidnan
```

Adding a link to a sample csv that shows the issue along with a complete version of my code (with some details removed)

[Example file to run with this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uLWZhaqRAEJqIHga6fgpeYhkUTsaAHU2)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import csv
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Ask for file
filename = os.path.abspath(askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select csv file", filetypes=(("CSV Files", "*.csv"),)))
# Set output file name
output_name = filename.rsplit('.')
del output_name[len(output_name) - 1]
output_name = "".join(output_name)
output_name += "_processed.csv"
# Using the file that will be written to
csv_output_file = open(os.path.abspath(output_name), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
# Using the file is be read in
csv_file = open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
# Define reader with , delimiter
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
# Define writer to put quotes around input values with a comma in them
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_output_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

header_row = []
# Iterate over the rows in the csv
for idx, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
    if idx != 0:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
    else:
        header_row = row
        csv_writer.writerow(header_row)
csv_file.flush()
csv_output_file.flush()
csv_file.close()
csv_output_file.close()
```

Expected results

```
Header1,Header2
Value1,TîezÑnmidnan
```

Actual results

```
Header1,Header2
Value1,Teznmidnan
```

Edit:
chardetect gave me "utf-8 with confidence 0.99"

Comment: The file is probably not utf-8 encoded. Try to find out the correct encoding. You can start here: https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding

Comment: It gave me "utf-8 with confidence 0.99"

Comment: Can you share the file with us? That might help to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Not really has it contains private information. It's your basic csv except it has some words that contain foreign letters. I'm working on a mac so maybe that's part of the issue with how it interprets things? Because if I open the file in textEdit or something I see the ? symbol, but if I open it in excel I can see the foreign letters as they should be. So somehow excel figured it out.

Comment: How about creating a sample csv that shows the same behavior but without containing sensitive data?

Comment: Add an example file and a more complete code sample of what I'm running (obviously looks silly because I removed how I'm actually processing it, which also proves the error has nothing to do with my parsing code)